# Child with a different last name from the biological father

Tags: united-states, children, birth-certificate

The Mother M and the father F conceive a child C. F leaves M and leaves the country before the birth of C. Subsequently, M marries a different person, H. A paternity test shows that F is the biological father.

Under US law, under which conditions would the last name of H be listed on the birth certificate? Does F have any say in this?

Comment: I removed the [tag:child-support] tag which does not appear relevant to the question as it stands.  The phrase "US law" should be made more specific, as questions about names and birth certificates are almost certainly covered by state law, not federal.

Comment: The question fails to specify whether the child C is before or after H and M are married.

Comment: It sounds like there is a question buried here and not recognized about how paternity determinations work in U.S. law.

Answer (score 7):

Under US law, there is no requirement for a child to have the same last name as the legal father, the biological father, or the mother. Initially the last name is specified on the birth certificate, often taken from the name of the listed father, but that is not required. But the name can be changed at any time, by a custodial parent or guardian while the child is minor, and later by the child directly.

Comment: Is that the case for all 50 states? It seems plausible that one or two states might have such requirements.

Comment: @nick012000
I do not think there is such a requirement in any US state.

Comment: "Does F have any say in this?" Certainly not if the father is absent. The decision on the name is made by the mother alone, at a minimum, if she is the only parent available to the hospital administrator preparing the birth certificate for the vital records department of the government.

Comment: @nick012000 I agree with David Siegel that there is no such U.S. state.